# On pointer basics in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Regarding pointers (in structs for this case), I understand that if 'a' were a struct and 'b' declared within the struct, then we can access the data through:

```
a->b
```

And now, I've recently found out C has a lot of shortcuts regarding pointers, one of which would be the arrow operator as above.

I've seen 'a->b' being written as '[a] + b', such that:

```
a->b <=> [a] + b //meaning that they are interchangeable
```

However, I am having trouble making sense of this what '[a] + b' actually means and would really appreciate someone laying the details out for me (or perhaps I misread and the above is nonsense !). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "I've seen 'a->b' being written as '[a] + b'..." Where'd you see that? That can't possibly be valid C syntax. The array subscript `[]` operator requires two arguments because the expression `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p+i)`. I can't see how `[a]` alone is valid C.

Comment: where did you see  `[a] + b` ? can you provide some example?

Comment: My teacher's study guide for our midterm tomorrow! >< If this is all silliness, perhaps he made a typo? I wasn't sure if there existed a 'square-brackets operator,' because it caught me off guard.

Comment: @honeywind: The `[]` operator certainly does exist, but the example you provided is not how they are used. Like I said, the `[]` operator is for accessing elements of an array, not members of a structure. That's what the `->` operator is for (so that `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`). You should certainly ask your teacher about this unusual "operator".

Comment: @In silico: Phew, thought I missed something really basic; must be a typo. Sorry for the silly question! I'm still a bit new to C and I appreciate you helping me out and the additional 'shortcut' information. ^^ I'll definitely ask him! Thank you.

Comment: IIRC some assembly languages use `[a]` to dereference `a`, so perhaps your teacher meant something along the lines of `*((char *)a + offsetof(a_type, b))`

Comment: @Chris Lutz: That's an interesting connection (I'm keen on learning assembly in the near future ^^)! If that's what he meant, teacher is too tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C language, `[a] + b` means nothing. It is a syntax error. Your book probably uses that notation to explain something, but out of context it means nothing. However, it is similar-looking enough to several other pointer shortcuts as to cause confusion. So to dispel that confusion, here are all the pointer shortcuts I can think of:

- `a->b` is a synonym for `(*a).b`, that is, accessing a member of a pointer to a `struct` type.
- `a[b]` is a synonym for `*(a + b)`, that is, accessing an array element by performing pointer arithmetic to a specified offset.

  - Note that, due to the above, `a[b]` is synonymous with `b[a]`, because `a[b]` <=> `*(a + b)` <=> `*(b + a)` <=> `b[a]`. Evil tricksters will do things like `0[x]` or `5["string"]` to confuse you. Fear not, for now you know the answer.
- `*&a` is a synonym for `a`, that is, dereferencing an address. It creates a pointer, then dereferences it immediately, yielding the original object.

  - Note that `&a[b]` translates to `&*(a + b)` which translates to `a + b`. Both `&a[b]` and `a + b` create pointers to an array element in the same way. Which way is the "best" way depends on personal preference, place of employment, and phase of the moon.
  - Note that `&*a` is not the same as `*&a`. The latter creates a pointer, then dereferences it, yielding the original object. The former assumes `a` is a pointer, dereferences it, then takes the address of the result, yielding the original pointer. `&*a` is mandated by the standard not to dereference the pointer and can be safely used on a `NULL` pointer.
- `*(type *)&a` is an evil hack that you may see from time to time. It takes the address of `a`, casts the pointer to a pointer to a `type`, and dereferences it. This is usually unspecified behavior*, but in practice will cause the bits of object `a` to be reinterpreted as a `type` object. This allows you to get at e.g. the bitwise representation of `float`s or other objects. There are perhaps better ways to accomplish that goal, but if you ever stumble across this line of code, you'll at least know what the authors intended by it.

I'll add more if I think of them.

*I say unspecified because, if you did `int i = -1; printf("%u\n", *(unsigned int)&i);`, the C standard doesn't mandate whether this would print the value `UINT_MAX` (for two's complement), `UINT_MAX - 1` (for one's complement) or `(unsigned int)INT_MAX + 2` (for sign-and-magnitude).

Comment: Wow this is beautiful. I will definitely be coming back to this post! (Why is C so evil? :P)

Comment: C (like all languages) is only as evil as you are.

Comment: @Chris Lutz Regarding possible undefined behaviour of pointer casts, I believe you are wrong. I cannot find anything in the standard labelling such casts as undefined or unspecified behaviour, they seem to be perfectly valid. The only related undefined behaviour is casts that results in incorrect alignment. This is all addressed in the standard below 6.3.2.3.

Comment: ISO 9899:1999 6.3.2.3.7 `- Conversion between two pointer types produces a result that is incorrectly aligned (A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned57) for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.`

Comment: @Lundin - Technically, that is sufficient, as the standard makes no specifications about the sizes or alignments of types (aside from the integer and floating-point hierarchies), so both `short s; *(int *)&s;` or `int i; *(long *)&i;` are at risk of alignment issues. You could preface all such casts with checking that the `sizeof`s (or `alignof` using `#define alignof(t) offsetof(struct {char c;t x;}, x)`) are equal, but that gets annoying quickly. However, I thought the UB was in the dereference. Perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: 6.5.3.2 paragraph 4 says "...If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undeﬁned."

Comment: @Chris Lutz 6.5.3.2 Is also concerned about alignment. There's a note 87 describing what "invalid value" means: `Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.`  Those things listed are clearly bugs. The reason I posted all this, is that there are lots of embedded systems using the *(type *)&a syntax without any problems, but then they are using nicely-made MCUs that don't have any alignment requirements at all.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, `[a]+b` isn't valid C. Maybe he meant

```
a->b <=> a[0].b
```

Comment: Or based off of Chris' post, 0[a].b (is that valid?) Wait till my Java friends hear this. :P

Comment: It's not valid because `0` is not a pointer. `((void*)0)` is a pointer but indexing it is invalid because void has no size. The closest you may get would be (provided that `sizeof(char)==1` and `sizeof(int)>=sizeof(a)`): `((char*)0)[(int)a].b` (I'm not really sure about the cast syntax, but you get the idea).

Comment: You're incorrect. The standard requires that, in the expression `a[b]`, one of `a` and `b` is a pointer, and the other an integer. It doesn't say which one must be which.